# Wordpress Paid Membership: Podcast 'Preview'?

Tags: wordpress

I'm currently working on a personal project that involves paid membership. So far I have been using Wordpress and s2member. Part of this blog is a weekly podcast, which will require a paid membership to listen to in its entirety.

I want to limit the amount of time that a non-member can listen to a podcast, and I would like to accomplish this without having to create 2 versions of the podcast. Is there a WP Plugin, or some kind of JS code that I can implement with the podcast player to limit playback to people that are not members?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Even if you find something like that, users would be able to get the full version from code. JS would stop the player and they wouldn't be able to play it further, but they can use other ways to get the full track and download it directly.

It's always better to have 2 versions so non-members have access only to is the cut off one.